# html forms, input leads to certain webpage

Tags: html, forms

i'm not a very good programmer at all but i need a little help with a webpage i'm making.

Here's what I have for a form:

```
<form name="input" action="name.htm" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

What I want it to do is if I put in the name **Fred** and press submit `Button`, it will go to a certain page. Any other name will link to another page or `popup` with an error saying, "tough luck!" or something like that.

Sorry, I couldn't find anything this specific on the web anywhere. I'm sure it's simple, I'm just confused with how this works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

using front-end only, i'd be using javascript or jquery. meaning you don't need a form element inside it.

```
<script>
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
window.location.replace("enter url here")
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with JS/jQuery:

HTML

```
<form name="input" action="name.htm" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#submit-button").click(function(){
  if ($("#name").val() == "Fred")
    location.href = "goodurl";
  else
    location.href = "badurl";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options to solve this problem.

- To use JavaScript for input value's validation and depending on it to redirect user
- To use server side language to check the passed value

The first option will be easier for you I guess.
You can do something like:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="redirect();">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function redirect() {
            var value = document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
            if (value == 'Fred') {
                window.location.href='http://url1';
            } else {
                window.location.href='http://url2';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Links: 'url1' and 'url2' must be replaced with your URLs

Comment: Thank you! this helped me the most. I couldn't get the other ones working properly with what I was using. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code in your HTML file and try it out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleSubmit() {
        var name = document.input.name.value;

        if(name == 'Fred') {
            location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        } else if (name == 'Jack') {
            location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        } else {
            alert("Tough Luck");
        }
    }
</script>    

    <form name="input" action="name.htm" method="get">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="handleSubmit();">
    </form>
```